# Laggy brightness control on Dell Inspirion using function keys - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, dell, brightness, amdgpu

I've been looking all over the internet to solve this problem. Already did every single suggestion I found regarding backlight manager or VGA adapter but nothing seems to work at all.

The volume keys work perfectly, but the moment I try to change the brightness using the FN key it gets laggy and throws it all the way up or down and clicking/typing gets slow and weird.

When adjusting it via settings menu it works though. And using the FN key on the login menu doesn't generate this problem.

I have a integrated AMD video card but it does not show under the command `lspci | grep VGA`, only under the description "Display Controller" with the command `sudo lshw -C video`. I presume only my Intel Integrated Graphics Controller is handling video on my system. Bellow is the result of each command:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

```
sudo lshw -C video
*-display                 
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versão: 09
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:48 memória:c0000000-c03fffff memória:b0000000-bfffffff porta de E/S:5000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       descrição: Display controller
       produto: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
       fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:03:00.0
       versão: 00
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=radeon latency=0
       recursos: irq:49 memória:a0000000-afffffff memória:c0500000-c053ffff porta de E/S:3000(tamanho=256) memória:c0540000-c055ffff
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick.

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and this worked for me. Have you tried?

The steps I followed are:

```
Opened the keyboard layout file for my language, in my case:
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br

Commented the line:
modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };

Logged out and logged in again.
```

These steps are specific for the Brazilian Portuguese ABNT2 Layout and may not work for other layouts, but it can help you find a similar solution.

The original posted by murilomentor on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/84453o/delayfreezecpu_spike_when_using_the_functionmedia/

Comment: Thank you Rafael! It's a bit slow but it works, nothing compared to before.